# Записать ArrayList<String[]> в txt файл

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Подскажите пожалуйста, как записать большой (5000 строк) `ArrayList<String[]>` в файл через разделитель. `String[]` состоит из 13 элементов.

Сейчас делаю так, перебираю все строки и добавляю между ними разделители, потом записываю в файл.. Но на 5000 строк уходит до 20 секунд, это очень долго..
"﹀" - это у меня разделители в текстовом файле..

```
ArrayList<String[]> myPoints;

...

public void mySavePoints(final String file_name) {
    String txt = "";  //составляем текст в файле
    if (myPoints.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {
            txt =  txt + myPoints.get(i)[0]                 + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[1].replaceAll("﹀", "^")   + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[2]                      + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[3]                      + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[4]                      + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[5].replaceAll("﹀", "^")   + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[6].replaceAll("﹀", "^")   + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[7].replaceAll("﹀", "^")   + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[8].replaceAll("﹀", "^")   + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[9].replaceAll("﹀", "^")   + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[10].replaceAll("﹀", "^")  + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[11].replaceAll("﹀", "^")  + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[12].replaceAll("﹀", "^")  + "\n";
        }
    }


    // поток
    final String finalTxt = txt;
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Сохраняем переменную в файл
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file_name);
                byte[] buffer = finalTxt.getBytes();
                fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(fos != null)
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            //конец потока
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте стринги соединять через StringBuilder

Comment: попробуйте сложение заменить StringBuffer, а внутри цикла один раз получить `myPoints.get(i)`

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста, если можно..

Comment: Лучше `StringBuilder` чем `StringBuffer`. Последний создавался для потокобезопасного, но более медленного программинга. Но в этой задаче разницы почти не будет.

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что объекты класса `String` - неизменяемы, то есть вы добавляя что-то к стринге, вы создаёте новый объект, сохранив старый. У вас - чистая утечка памяти. Используйте класс `StringBuilder` - это аналог `String`, только изменяемый. 
Итак:

Создайте объект класса StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(""); //Строка для записи массива строк
```

В эту строку запишите весь массив строк.

```
for(int i = 0; i<myPoints.size(); i++){
    out.append(myPoints.get(i));
    }
```

Полученную строку запишите в txt.

По моему авторитетному мнению, должно получаться 0.5-5 секунд на всё.

Comment: Хочу попробовать ваш метод, но не пойму, как сделать.. Нижний пример работает быстрее чем было, но тоже долго..

Comment: @Alex455 поправил код, чтобы вам было понятно. Вы создаёте строку стринг билдера. Извлекаете из массива и добавляете по одному элементу к строке `out`.

Comment: Это очень-очень просто, если непонятки - пишите в коммент.

Comment: Так что ли? Опять плюсы StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(""); 
        for(int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++){
            out.append(myPoints.get(i)[0] + myPoints.get(i)[1].replaceAll("﹀", "^") + myPoints.get(i)[2] + ...);
        }
        txt = out.toString();

Comment: Чуть-чуть не так. Наверное попробуйте вынести строку перед циклом:
`StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");

for(int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++){

 str = myPoints.get(i).replaceAll("﹀", "^");

out.append(str);
}`

Comment: В смысле одну ещё одну строку сделайте для записи, которая грохнет ваши разделители. Потом этот кусок пришейте к строке out.

Comment: ахда. Методом аппенд так же всуньте ваши новые разделители в цикл. 
`out.append("﹀");`

Comment: У меня так работает: StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("");
        for(int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++){
            out.append(myPoints.get(i)[0] + "﹀" + myPoints.get(i)[1].replaceAll("﹀", "^") + "﹀" + myPoints.get(i)[2] + "﹀" +
                    myPoints.get(i)[3] + "﹀"  +myPoints.get(i)[4] + "﹀" + myPoints.get(i)[5].replaceAll("﹀", "^") +    -//-     +"﹀" + myPoints.get(i)[12].replaceAll("﹀", "^") + "\n");
        } Я не вижу в вашем последнем примере составления строки из 13 переменных с разделителем "﹀", или я не так что-то понимаю..

Comment: Всеравно не понял, куда 13 переменных вставлять, так же нельзя писать - myPoints.get(i).replaceAll("﹀", "^"), ошибку выдает, надо же как-то myPoints.get(i)[0], myPoints.get(i)[1] и тд.. Буду благодарен если напишите как должно быть, чтобы больше не гадать..

Comment: Так так, я начинаю понимать. У вас не просто массив строк. У вас - массив массивов строк. В каждом по 13 элементов, всего же строк array.size()*13. Так?

Comment: Да, там же ArrayList<String[]>, в String[] 13 переменных, которые в файл записываются через разделитель "﹀", чтобы потом загружаться так же обратно при запуске программы..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81716/discussion-between-andrew-kachalin-and-alex455).

Answer (score 5):

Время у вас уходит на создание огромного количества строк в цикле, это классическая ошибка, о которой много где написано.

Плюс к этому непонятно, зачем сперва делать делать строку, а потом писать её, если можно сразу писать в файл? Таким образом вам не нужно держать эту большую строку в памяти:

```
private static final Set<Integer> REPLACE_INDEXES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12));
private final int STRING_ARRAY_SIZE = 13;

public void mySavePoints(final String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < STRING_ARRAY_SIZE; j++){
            if(REPLACE_INDEXES.contains(j)){
                fw.write(myPoints.get(i)[j].replaceAll("﹀", "^"));
            } else {
                fw.write(myPoints.get(i)[j]);
            }
            fw.write('﹀');
        }
        fw.write("\n");
    }
    fw.close();
}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш код, но что-то он не сохраняет ничего, и то что было в файле удаляет..

Comment: следует в конце функции вызвать `fw.close()`, чтобы сохранял (добавил в код в ответе), а удаляет предыдущее и ваш код так же. Чтобы файл "дописывался", в конструкторе `FileWriter` есть второй параметр `append`, соответственно нужно писать так: `new FileWriter(fileName, true);`